# Sort on basis of given order in javaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have array of object like :

```
var array = [
    { id: 1, color: red,    value: 1 },
    { id: 2, color: red,    value: 2 },
    { id: 3, color: yellow, value: 3 },
    { id: 4, color: yellow, value: 4 },
    { id: 5, color: green,  value: 4 }
];
```

I want sorted order where green -> yellow -> red

after `array.sort(custmeSort())`
output should be

```
[
    { id: 5, color: green,  value: 4 },   
    { id: 3, color: yellow, value: 3 },
    { id: 4, color: yellow, value: 4 },
    { id: 1, color: red,    value: 1 },
    { id: 2, color: red,    value: 2 }
]
```

How to achive this in javascript.

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. What should happen when the two elements have identical `color` properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @Andreas It's not a duplicate, because it's not alphabetical sorting.

Comment: any order in case duplicate is fine

Comment: like all green will come first then all yellow then red

Comment: do you need to sort the value as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one object to set sorting order, and then just use `sort()`

```js
var array = [
  {id: 1, color: 'red',value: 1},
  {id: 2, color: 'red',value: 2},
  {id: 3, color: 'yellow',value: 3},
  {id: 4, color: 'yellow',value: 4},
  {id: 5, color: 'green',value: 4},
]
var order = {
  green: 1,
  yellow: 2, 
  red: 3
}

var result = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return order[a.color] - order[b.color];
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @NenadVracar if sort function return -ve then it swap and +ve then it don't swap ??